# OpenCV install opencv_contrib on Windows

Tags: python, opencv, opencv-contrib

I am using **OpenCV 3.1.0** , **Python 2.7.11** and **Windows 10.** I want to build the extra modules (**opencv_contrib**) into OpenCV.

I follow the step in this [GitHub](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib).

```
$ cd <opencv_build_directory>
$ cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv_contrib>/modules <opencv_source_directory>
$ make -j5
```

When I type `cmake _DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=C:\opencv_contrib\opencv_contrib/modules C:\opencv\sources`, there is an **error**.

[image]

I am looking for help how can I solve it. Thank you.

Comment: how did you use make on windows?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> **Update 29-5-2017: This also works with OpenCV 3.2.0-dev. Now using Visual
> Studio 2015 or 2017 gives no errors**.

**The cv2.pyd is now automatically moved to site-packages. You just only need to copy the DLLs.**

> As mentioned by [@AleksandrUsarov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517983/opencv-install-opencv-contrib-on-windows#comments-39361161) in the comments section, this method still works for OpenCV 4.1.2, but you need to check `OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE` parameter as well.

I have made a tutorial on how to compile and build your own OpenCV 3.1.0-dev from scratch. It is simple and organized and works with me very well. If you have time to recompile OpenCV check out the [tutorial](https://youtu.be/MXqpHIMdKfU).

The steps to follow are:

1. Install Visual Studio 2013
2. Install [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/)
3. Download both opencv and opencv_contrib from [github](https://github.com/opencv)
4. Create a directory `opencv-3.1.0-dev` and in this directory create other two directories one called `build` and the other called `sources`. The `paths` will be `opencv-3.1.0-dev\build` and `opencv-3.1.0-dev\sources`.
5. Unzip `opencv-master.zip`and `opencv_contrib-master.zip`
6. In the sources directory created in step 4, paste `opencv` and `opencv_contrib` directories
7. Open CMake and provide two paths, one for the build directory and the other for the sources directory

[image: cmake]

8. Press **configure**, a lot of lines highlighted in red will appear.

[image: configure]

9. before these lines appear you will have to specify your compiler. (Also select correct bit version based on your needs, same procedure works for 32-bt and 64-bit)

[image: compiler]

10. Choose whatever you want to build, but the most important thing to do is to provide the path of the non-free modules.

[image: extra modules]

11. Press **configure** again and new lines will be highlighted in red.
12. Make sure to uncheck BUILD_opencv_contrib_world before pressing generate.

[image: new]

13. The last step with CMake is to press **generate**.
14. Make sure `generating is done` before continuing.

[image: generating done]

15. open the build that was empty and you will find a bunch of files. The most important file is `OpenCV.sln`. Right click on this .sln file and open it with the visual studio 2013 used in CMake.

[image: the sln file]

**Be patient as this step and the next will take a lot of time.**

16. Build the 3 files with the order in the following image. Change the mode into `Release`. These step take about 10 to 15 minutes.

[image: build]

17. Copy all the `.dll` files [present at `opencv-3.1.0-dev\build\bin\Release`] and the `cv2.pyd` and paste them in the `site-packages` directory in `Pyhton27\Lib\site-packages`.
18. To verify the build open Python and execute `import cv2`. If no errors, execute `cv2.__version__`, and you should get `3.1.0-dev`.

[image: verification]

If anything is not clear please watch the tutorial provided at the beginning of this answer.

Comment: Instructions still work for 3.2.0-dev except: (1) step 16 only need to build INSTALL and (2) step 17 the .pyd file is already copied over for you but still need to copy over all the dlls

Comment: @GroovyDotCom You can also use Visual Studio 2015 for compiling the 3.2.0-dev version.

Comment: Thank you for this!! I just ran it on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2017 and it worked fine (except I had to exclude the opencv folder in my antivirus as it didn't like the EXEs being built.) You're a legend :)

Comment: @LucasYoung So glad I helped :)

Comment: Compiling OpenCV using Python 3.7 does not work but I have successfully compiled it using Python 3.4

Comment: Still works for 4.1.2 but need to check OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE parameter

Answer (score 15):

For Python 3.6/3.5 you could use *.whl (Python on Wheels) module [from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv):

```
pip install opencv_python-3.2.0+contrib-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

For Python 2.7 there is no opencv+contrib in one module, but you could separately install opencv module without contrib [from here at the end of the page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python) and then add `opencv-contrib-python` module:

```
pip install opencv_python-3.2.0.7-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Do not mix opencv+contrib `opencv-python (3.2.0+contrib)` and `opencv-contrib-python (3.2.0.7)` modules, otherwise your "`import cv2`" stop to work till you delete `opencv-contrib-python` module.

Comment: i had an python 3 error where openCV did not find some of the contrib functions, i got it working by following your second example and "opencv_python-3.3.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"

Comment: how about opencv-contrib-python-nonfree? any Idea how to install it

Answer (score 9):

no need for complex stuff, just uninstall the version of opencv you have and do:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Good luck, 
Amber

Answer (score 3):

The answer of [foo bar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7550928/foo-bar) is the best simple way to add opencv_contrib to python. But opencv_python-3.2.0.7-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is just for AMD chips. If you run it on Intel chip you will receive error message like this: "XXX is not a supported wheel on this platform". In this case, you must use opencv_python-3.2.0.7-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl.

Comment: I've got this error `Requirement 'opencv_python-3.2.0.7-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist`

Comment: To Vasyl Zvarydchuk -- You should download this file from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv according to your version of Python (2.7, 3.4, 3.6, etc.) and according to your version of Windows (32bit or 64bit). Better with contributions (`contrib`). But first try to use command: `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: amd64 means 64-bit architecture, not AMD chips per se, whereas the alternative package you suggested will work with 32-bit machines.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have no compiler installed or it is not found.

I have successfully worked with this guide:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-rc1/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html

However, it was necessary to use Visual Studio 12 2013, other versions did not work.

Comment: Does it mean that I need to install Visual Studio?

Comment: You will need some sort of c compiler. There are alternatives to visual studio, but it won't work without compiler.