# How to add opencv contrib to opencv for python

Tags: python-2.7, installation, opencv3.0

I was wondering how to add opencv contrib to python 2.7. I've been told I need it to run some code but don't know how to add it to opencv, which I have previously installed. I run Python 2.7 on Windows 10. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Which os are you using ?

Comment: I am running Windows 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV install opencv\_contrib on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517983/opencv-install-opencv-contrib-on-windows)

Comment: You could use my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43805213/7550928