# How to add "Tracker" in openCV python 2.7

Tags: python, opencv, tracker

I’m working with python 2.7 and opencv 3.1
I want to run a code for tracking objects by this:

```
import cv2
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Set up tracker.
    # Instead of MIL, you can also use
    # BOOSTING, KCF, TLD, MEDIANFLOW or GOTURN

    tracker = cv2.Tracker_create("MIL")

    # Read video
    video = cv2.VideoCapture("videos/chaplin.mp4")

    # Exit if video not opened.
    if not video.isOpened():
        print "Could not open video"
        sys.exit()

    # Read first frame.
    ok, frame = video.read()
    if not ok:
        print 'Cannot read video file'
        sys.exit()

    # Define an initial bounding box
    bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)

    # Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box
    # bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)

    # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
    ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)
```

but when I run it, I face with this error:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Tracker_create'`

Here is the source code : http://www.learnopencv.com/object-tracking-using-opencv-cpp-python/
I’m searching for solutions but I can’t find anything useful…
what can I do to add this module to my opencv library?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just install opencv-contrib-python

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

and it will work !

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest and fastest method is to install via the .whl files.  @foobar gives the answer in the post @kyjanond links to, but you can obtain the .whl files from the following links.

OpenCV: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python/3.3.0.10

OpenCV Contrib: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-contrib-python/3.3.0.10

I installed OpenCV 3.3.0 on Python 2.7, so I downloaded:

- opencv_python-3.3.0.10-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- opencv_contrib_python-3.3.0.10-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

To install, I ran:

- python -m pip install opencv_python-3.3.0.10-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- python -m pip install opencv_contrib_python-3.3.0.10-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

This worked, but in the updated version of OpenCV, the way the tracker functions are called have changed.

The original code in the GitHub repository was:

---

```
tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN']

tracker_type = tracker_types[1]

tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
```

---

I changed this to

---

```
tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN']

tracker_type = tracker_types[1]

if tracker_type == tracker_types[0]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
elif tracker_type == tracker_types[1]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
elif tracker_type == tracker_types[2]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
elif tracker_type == tracker_types[3]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
elif tracker_type == tracker_types[4]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
elif tracker_type == tracker_types[5]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
```

---

This approach seemed to work well for me.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you didn't compile your OpenCV with opencv_contrib modules. You have to recompile it. You can find a very good step-by-step tutorial how to do that in [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) blogpost.

**EDIT:**

If you need to compile it on Windows you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517983/opencv-install-opencv-contrib-on-windows) great tutorial by @Osama

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks...
it's great... but i need it in windows rather that Ubuntu
do you know how can i do it in windows 8?

Comment: @Elahe I added a link to stackoverflow tutorial that is describing compiling on Windows.

Comment: for me, using the [whl-file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43805213/3582159) was the most convenient way. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Once Installation is over.  All files are installed in
`/usr/local/` folder.
But to use it, your Python should be able to find
`OpenCV` module.

You have two options for that.

1. Move  the  module  to  any  folder  in  Python  Path: Python  path  can  be  found  out  by  entering `import sys;print sys.path` in Python terminal.  It will print out many locations. Move `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so` to any of this folder. For example, `su mv /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so /usr/lib/python2.7/` → site-packages. But you will have to do this every time you install `OpenCV`.
2. Add `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to the `PYTHON_PATH`: It is to be done only once. Just open `~/.bashrc` and add following line to it, then log out and come back. `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. Thus OpenCV installation is finished. Open a terminal and try
   import cv2.

Answer (score 0):

New versions of openCV use for example: TrackerKCF_create() notation.

You can find new examples [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/tracking/samples/tracker.py)