# unable to run self.tracker = cv2.Tracker_create() on opencv 4.X on win10

Tags: python, opencv, video-tracking

```
self.tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'Tracker_create'
```

I have tried the method supported in [Unable to run Tracking on Open CV 3.4.1 on Python 3.6.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52456690/2749397), but it does not work.

```
self.tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem just now . just uninstall your opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python, then pip install  opencv-contrib-python==3.4.5.20