# OpenCV not implementing GOTURN file

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting this message when I try to create a tracker:
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerGOTURN_create'

I've downloaded goturn.caffemodel and goturn.prototxt, and they are in the same folder as my python file.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
#import time

ballTracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "Tracker" in openCV python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387322/how-to-add-tracker-in-opencv-python-2-7)