# Build opencv with contrib vs2015 c++

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to build opencv_contrib because i need face module. I am folowing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517983/opencv-install-opencv-contrib-on-windows) tutorial (without python part).
When I build ALL_BUILD in debug mode it is ok. But when I try this in release mode I am getting this error"

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'D:\opencv2\opencv-3.2.0\build\bin\Release\opencv_version.exe'
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you included the necessary "Additional include directories", "Additional library directories" and "Additional dependencies" in the properties of your project?  Remember that you should add the proper paths in Debug and Release accordingly in the configuration window. You can take a look at this link. http://mcfloundinho.tk/install-opencv.html . Also have in mind that prefix "d" is for debug mode when you set the "Additional dependencies", otherwise set it without the prefix.

Comment: I built OpenCV 3.2 with Contrib module, including 'face', for Python 2.7 without any problem on Win10 64-bit through VC14 two months ago. Not sure what's the problem you encountered with one line of error message. Alternatively, you may check [OpenCv 3.2 Binary](https://github.com/cesardelgadof/OpenCVBinaries) if it fits. The binary included 'face'.

Answer (score 1):

I just pushed my OpenCV 3.2, with opencv_contrib modules, binary to [github](https://github.com/CCM2016/opencv-3.2.0_binary). You may have a trial if you haven't solved your problem.