# Problems with building OpenCV 3.2 and python bindings on Windows

Tags: python, opencv, cmake

I am attempting to build OpenCV on Windows 10 with extra modules and python bindings (and thus following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517983/opencv-install-opencv-contrib-on-windows)), and I'm running into some issues. Firstly, I am only seeing a Visual Studio project called "opencv_python3" under the "bindings" folder, and not the project for python2. I am not seeing any errors related to this in CMake and filling in the appropriate variables for python 2 like I am with python 3.

Comment: Concerning "strike" edit: Unlike to many other forums, on Stack Overflow we tend to maintain posts (questions and answers) as contained **latest information only**. If you think some part of the question post is outdated, simply **remove** this part: such a way the post will contain only **actual problem** (for which you want to get an answer). For those who interested in original post's content, there is a *revisions history*.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by installing Python 2.7 (64 bit). I had previously been trying to install OpenCV with Python 2.7 (32 bit). I can't speak to whether or not it is possible to install OpenCV 3.2 with Python 2.7 (32 bit) bindings, but making this change did work *for me*.