# Python 3.6.4 install OpenCV 3.4.0 and Opencv contrib on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, opencv, cmake

I am using **OpenCv 3.4.0**, **Python 3.6.4**, **Cmake 3.10.2**, **OpenNI-Windows-x64-2.2**, **SensorKinect093-Bin-Win32-v5.1.2.1**, **Visual Studio 2015** and **Windows 10**. I want to build the cv2.pyd for Python 3.6.4.

I follow the step in many others way such as github and [OpenCV install opencv_contrib on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517983/opencv-install-opencv-contrib-on-windows)

After configure in the Cmake, It shows the output about python 3 like this:

```
 Python (for build):            C:/Users/zhong/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe
```

And the Cmake havn't the **BUILD_opencv_python3**, **PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR** and **PYTHON3_LIBRARY**, so I append the Bool value of **BUILD_opencv_python3** and the locations of PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR, PYTHON3_LIBRARY manually. The locations are as followings:

```
PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE     C:/Users/zhong/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe
PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR    C:/Users/zhong/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/include
PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR2      
PYTHON3_LIBRARY        C:/Users/zhong/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/libs/python36.lib
PYTHON3_LIBRARY_DEBUG    
PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS  C:/Users/zhong/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include
PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH  C:/Users/zhong/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages
```

After that, Cmake can't find the Libraries of Python3, albeit it have the correct location of PYTHON3_LIBRARY. The output about Python3 in Cmake like this:

```
Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Users/zhong/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe (ver 3.6.4)
    Libraries:                   NO
    numpy:                       C:/Users/zhong/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.14.0)
    packages path:               C:/Users/zhong/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages

  Python (for build):            C:/Users/zhong/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe
```

How can I configure the python 3.6.4 with Cmake correctlly? I want to use deep camera so I have to compile the Opencv with OPENNI2.

I am looking for help how can I solve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect error messages described the problem to be **in the question post itself as text**, not linked as images. Please, edit your question post and correct this. (After copy-pasting error message to the question post, you may format it with `{}` button.)

Comment: I am so sorry !! It is my first time use Stack Overflow and I don't know how to show the image...I will try to edit it correctly

Comment: Why not just `pip install opencv-contrib-python` ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Because I want to use deep camera such as Kinect with OPENNI2. So I have to build the cv2.pyd

Answer (score 0):

I give up the **python 3**, and install the **python 2.7.14**, **OpenCV 3.2.0** instead.

Following the step in [OpenCV install opencv_contrib on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517983/opencv-install-opencv-contrib-on-windows) is easy to install...

It take me too much time to install, I suppose that OpenCV 3.4.0 do not support for Python 3.6.4.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this site which contains instructions:
https://www.scivision.co/install-opencv-python-windows/

I was able to use the "pip install opencv-contrib-python" command to have it auto downloaded and installed.  I am using Python 3.7 (but it should also work for the version you listed) and have an anaconda environment activated.  If you use anaconda, just make sure you install pip for the environment you are using and activate it before using the pip install command.

Comment: Note that the conda version of opencv might be broken still.