# OpenCV contrib on windows c++ (not all stuff included)

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, installation, opencv-contrib

I am having problem with bulding contrib. Some libraries arent generated after runing BUILD and INSTALL scripts in visual studio. (doing for both release and debug). I followed these manuals:

[OpenCV install opencv_contrib on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517983/opencv-install-opencv-contrib-on-windows)

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib

My steps:

1. I have tried to create new build using cmake. From openCV 4.5.1 and openCV 4.5.1 contrib
2. I need opencv2/cudafeatures2d.hpp, so I was looking for it
3. When I first openned cmakeGUI, after giving path for EXTRA modules I saw line with opencv2_cudafeatures2d and all others modules = checked.
4. I pressed configurate again, to get rid off red lines
5. generate button presed
6. in visual studio BUILD
7. INSTALLed into "install" folder"

I have project using cv, everything works fine, except some contrib fuatures I am working on now.
for example, I was able to work with "opencv2/xfeatures2d/cuda.hpp" (in code cuda::SURF), part of OpenCV quessing.

still opencv2/cudafeatures2d.hpp not installed, so I came back to cmake and I couldnt find it again ("opencv2_cudafeatures2d"), EXTRA modules parameter still here, nothing is changing after pressing configure...

I also tried to include paths from contrib folder directory, but then Linker poped up that he cannot open some .lib file...

any help? any idea?

Comment: Now I am repeating stepps and I cannot find cudafeatures2d line ... lol... so weird..

Answer (score 1):

parameter:

WITH_CUDA            must be checked

BUILD_CUDA_STUBS     must be checked

as well to include CUDA libraries from contrib version.